# unable to access local home network from web page php with snmp

Tags: php, snmp, vps

I can monitoring my local network with a simple code in php. I use xammp. For example:

```
<?php
    echo ' my computer = ';
    $a = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
    echo $a;
    echo "<br>";

    echo ' my computer (ip) = ';
    $device = snmpget("192.168.1.131", "public", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
    echo $device;
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
```

OUTPUT:

my computer = STRING: "Hardware: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 AT/AT COMPATIBLE - Software: Windows Version 6.3 (Build 19043 Multiprocessor Free)"

my computer (ip) = STRING: "Hardware: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 AT/AT COMPATIBLE - Software: Windows Version 6.3 (Build 19043 Multiprocessor Free)"

By changing the ip and OID I can obtain information about printers and other devices on my network.

I tried this code in my shared hosting and it does not work nor can it work because from customer service they say that snmp is only active in VPS Hosting

I am currently testing a vps to try to get data with snmp from my local network without success. Would it be possible to do this? I'm a great newbie to VPS

My server is Ubuntu 18 and my provider is Hostinger

Answer (score 0):

well, now I can get info from my vps:

```
$a = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
output:
STRING: "Linux tallerdeapps.com 4.15.0 #1 SMP Thu Apr 22 16:18:59 MSK 2021 x86_64"
```

My mistake was not installing php-snmp right. I was editing php.ini with no result. What works is:
apt-get install php-snmp

service snmpd restart

service apache2 restart

Now, my big question is if it is possible by php-snmp to obtain data using  a php webpage in my vps from a LAN

In this code 192.168.1.131 is my local computer ip